# File formatting-variable based indentation

Tags: python, file, if-statement, formatting

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[(1, u'Category'), (2, u'Item'), (3, u'SubItem'), (4, u'N/A'), (1, u'Features'), (2, u'Tool Baseline')]
```

I want to write to a file using indentations based off the first element of each tuple:

```
Category
    Item
         SubItem
            N/A
Features
    Tool Baseline
```

I'm new to Python and I'm looking for a simple way to do this other than:

```
if tup[0] == 1
    file.write('\t')
    file.write(tup[1])
```

(These tuples used to be part of a multi-layered tree, and each number represents a branch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply strings! In the following `pair[0]*'\t'` will give you `pair[0]` tab characters.

```
>>> x = [(1, u'Category'), (2, u'Item'), (3, u'SubItem'), (4, u'N/A'), (1, u'Features'), (2, u'Tool Baseline')]
>>> for pair in x:
...   print pair[0]*'\t' + pair[1]
...
    Category
            Item
                    SubItem
                            N/A
    Features
            Tool Baseline
>>>
```

Just replace the printing with your file I/O operations.

```
file.write('\t'*tup[0])
file.write(tup[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is more awesome than you think it is:

```
file.write('\t' * tup[0])
file.write(tup[1])
```